# How to audit registration/unregistration of DLL/OCX in Windows

Tags: windows

We ship an application that uses a third-party component that requires an OCX file to be registered through regsvr32. Something (I suspect an application that uses the third-party component) on one customer's fleet of Terminal Servers is causing the OCX file to repeatedly be unregistered.

Is there some way to track down exactly what application is doing the unregistration of this DLL in Windows?

Comment: Terminal server may give the user a different ID from time to time. That can unregister the OCX. Can you trace with SysInternals ProcMon ?

Comment: @John will tracing the registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\ give me the app that's unregistering it?

Can you please elaborate a bit more on Terminal Server giving a different ID to the user (i.e. ID of what, how does this happen)? I did think DLL registration was system wide due to being in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: I cannot tell you if the registry key will help trace. Proc Mon is more real time. Terminal Server often set up with fewer seats that people (not everyone needs TS at the same time) and so ID's can change. Unlike a Personal Computer with the same user.

Comment: Thanks for the info - what would I tell ProcMon to trace if not the registry key though? And sorry I'm still not quite sure what ID you are saying would change to remove the DLL registration - is this an ID of the user - and if so how does this affect the registration of the DLL which is computer-wide?

Comment: See what apps are changing the OCX